# Activity Not opening from the notification bar

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, cordova-plugins, urbanairship.com

When I click on the Notification the app is not open.

Comment: Post the code you use to create the notifications.

Comment: @David Wasser  i have updated the post. pls check it

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any code here that **creates** a Notification. Post the code that creates the Notification please

Comment: @DavidWasser This is Urban Airship plugin. In plugin it self it have the create notification function is there.

Comment: Is it getting to the receiver? What about the activity? The one thing that really stands out to me is multiple calls to `setFlags`. The last set will win. To set multiple flags or them together `setFlags(IIntent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | ... )`

Comment: @ralepinski thanks for comment. But i used same thing as you suggested. but till is  not working.

Comment: Were you able to solve this yet? I'm curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have setFloags like below. now it is working.

```
 i.setFlags (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
```